# sketch guided image generation using cross-attention injection?

Tags: image-generation, diffusion-models

I have seen some papers that allow a diffusion model to generate an image that is compatible with a sketch, such as ["Sketch-Guided Text-to-Image Diffusion Models"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.13752) [1], which trains a module to allow this. My question is can this not be done in a simpler way, by injecting an attention map that is compatible with the sketch for the relevant object in the cross-attention? for example in the added image (taken from [1]) for the token "bicycle" an attention map compatible with the sketch can override the original created attention map.

[image]